# How to access state from a function

Tags: reactjs

```js
this.state = {
            color: {
              B: '#FFB1C2', // RED
              C: '#A7EBEB', // GREEN
              D: '#99BFFF', // BLUE
              E: '#F9C499', // ORANGE
              F: '#B2A9A7', // BROWN
              DEFAULT: '#B7C7CE' // DEFAULT
            }
}

changeChartColor = (color) => {
   this.setState({ B: color.hex })
};
```

I'm using a react library to change color from screen, `(color)` at the function responds with `color` I picked data. How can I access `this.state.color.B` at the `changeChartColor` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just like any other regular js object

```
this.state.color.B
```

if you need to access it after it was set, use a callback function, since `setState` is not synchronous

```
this.setState({ B: color.hex }, () => this.state.color.B)
```

If you need to set your `color.B`, use spread syntax to update `color` object

```
this.setState({
   color: {
       ...this.state.color,
       ...{
           B: color.hex
       }
   }
})
```

With `B` being a complex object spread syntax can be chained. You are not limited to updating single field.

```
this.setState({
   color: {
       ...this.state.color,
       ...{
           B: {
               ...this.state.color.B,
               ...{
                   r: 'R',
                   // update all or some of `B` fields.
               }
           },
           C: {
               ...this.state.color.C,
               ...{
                   g: 'G',
               }
           }
       }
   }
})
```

If you have completely new state with all colors updated, it is easier just to do

```
this.setState({
       color: {
           ...this.state.color,
           ...newColorObject
       }
});
```

Comment: `this.setState({this.state.color.B: color.hex})` I'm trying this but throws syntax error

Comment: you were asking how to access it, not how to set. will update my solution accordingly

Comment: it works but what if I were to have a `r, g, b,a` state inside the B: how would I set that?

Comment: Makes sense, but what if I wanted to do for C, D and so on for 30 other letters. Will I Need a new this.setstate?

Comment: updated code, you are not limited to updating 1 nested field in setState, but if you have completely new object, it is easier to set it as a whole rather than updating all 30 letters

Comment: I'm trying the one before last method but it's throwing syntax error after ...this.state.color, when you open the ` { } ` brackets.

Comment: fixed, please check

Comment: It doesn't throw any error, color changes but it changes for all values that I add on `this.setState`.

In my example I added both B and C and when I change both of them change to the same color.

Comment: sorry, it is unclear for me, maybe you could create new question

Comment: Do you have a discord or any other platform where we can discuss?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64536269/how-can-i-automate-a-way-to-be-able-to-edit-colors-rgba-values-in-this-state - hope this might tell you more about the issue